# How to send messages to all clients in multithread chat server?

Tags: c#, multithreading, list, sockets, chat

Sorry for asking about the 'same' thing over and over again. It's yet another edition of the chat. With a lot of searching around I've finally found out how to pass the client list (or at least I hope so) to the `Chat` function.

However I don't know if this is even supposed to work:

Everytime a client connects :

```
clients.Add(clientSocket);
```

`var ctThread = new System.Threading.Thread(() => Chat(clients));`

where the `Chat` function hopefully correctly receives the clients via

`public void Chat(List<TcpClient> clients)`

and then writes this out

```
 foreach (var client in clients)
    {
        writer.Write(message);
    }
```

With the client having 2 threads (not sure if they can actually read/write at the same time)

```
    Thread ctThread = new Thread(Write);
    Thread ctThread2 = new Thread(Read);
    ctThread2.Start();
    ctThread.Start();
```

Did I pass the client list to the function properly? and can it actually correctly send the messages? Because right now the server is not responding to anything that I type on the client.

Full code:

**Server**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;

namespace MultiServeris
{
    class Multiserveris
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TcpListener ServerSocket = new TcpListener(1000);         
            ServerSocket.Start();                                     
            List<TcpClient> clients = new List<TcpClient>();
            Console.WriteLine("Server started.");
            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient clientSocket = ServerSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
                handleClient client = new handleClient();
                clients.Add(clientSocket);
                client.startClient(clientSocket,clients);
            }
        }
    }

    public class handleClient
    {
        TcpClient clientSocket;                                 
        public void startClient(TcpClient inClientSocket, List<TcpClient> clients)
        {
            this.clientSocket = inClientSocket;
            var ctThread = new System.Threading.Thread(() => Chat(clients)); 
        }

        public void Chat(List<TcpClient> clients)
        {
            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(clientSocket.GetStream());
            BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(clientSocket.GetStream());
            while (true)
            {
                string message = reader.ReadString();
                foreach (var client in clients)
                {
                    writer.Write(message);
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Client**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;


namespace Klientas
{
    class Klientas
    {
        public static void Write()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient clientSocket = new TcpClient("localhost", 1000);
                string str = Console.ReadLine();
                BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(clientSocket.GetStream());
                writer.Write(str);
            }
        }
        public static void Read()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient clientSocket = new TcpClient("localhost", 1000);
                BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(clientSocket.GetStream());
                string message = reader.ReadString();
                Console.WriteLine(message);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args){
            Thread ctThread = new Thread(Write);
            Thread ctThread2 = new Thread(Read);
            ctThread2.Start();
            ctThread.Start();
           }
    }
}
```

Comment: is it a requirement to use TcpClient? are you doing this as an exercise? Why not look at frameworks like SignalR?

Comment: Once created a TCP/IP set of methods, but it was 6-7 years ago, can't remember much. But I do remember that instead of TcpClient I found it easier to work directly with Socket. You ask "not sure if they can actually read/write at the same time" - yes, with proper multi-threading you can have many, many Socket connections running at the same time, reading and/or writing simultaneously. There are lots of resources on the Internet about this, just search "C# chat tcp/ip".

Comment: Yes, it has to be done using TcpClient. I thought I've worked out most of the problems already. Don't know what's missing for the server to correctly write to the clients. (Or if the clients multithreading actually works as it is right now)

Answer (score 1):

TCP is not design for broadcasting which is why you're having to loop through all your clients. A better approach would be to use a protocol that supports brodcast use the SignalR Framework or if you want baremetal access use UDP. Here's a great SignalR chat example.

https://dhavalupadhyaya.wordpress.com/tag/signalr-chat-example/

Comment: Isn't SignalR only applicable to clients that use web browser technology? (Which may or may not be OK for the OP.) And I doubt that UDP is feasible, unless all chat clients are on the same network segment as the chat server. You certainly won't be getting UDP through firewalls or out through the Internet.

Comment: I cannot use a framework. It has to be done as close as possible to what I have so far. Any ideas what's wrong? Is the server writing to clients not working, or is it the client threads to read/write?